# Nginx SSL_do_handshake failed routines SSL3_CHECK_CLIENT_HELLO

Tags: nginx, ssl

I found this in my error log:

```
2012/05/29 14:01:02 [crit] 30038#0: *4186107 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14124145:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CLIENT_HELLO:multiple sgc restarts) while SSL handshaking, client: 80.208.151.166, server: iridium
```

Any idea what this is about?

Answer (score 2):

This error message appears to have been added to the OpenSSL code in response to [CVE-2011-4619](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-4619).

The error occurs if the client has restarted its client handshake more than once in a single connection negotiation, instead of the server allowing the client to repeatedly restart the handshake and keep a connection open forever.

So, you have a misbehaving SSL client, which may be either unintentional or malicious.  Either way, your SSL server responded by stopping the connection on the second attempt at restarting the handshake process, which is good!  Probably nothing to worry about, unless it's persistently repeated.